# Krusader (GNOME), File Already Exists dialog: make default button - Overwrite

Tags: gnome, krusader

Is there any solution do not use shortcuts and just confirm by Enter in case i need replace some files using Krusader? By default Krusader ask and set focus on **Cancel** button, when i get **File Already Exists** dialog.

Comment: I don't use Krusader but most panels offer accelerator keys such that if `Cancel` is default you can press `R` to replace instead of left arrow and Enter or using mouse.

Comment: I tried this on Kubuntu 18.04. There, the focus is on the filename in the box that allows you to suggest another filename. Hit `Tab` twice and then press `Enter` to complete the moving/overwriting operation.

Comment: Yes, in my case i try to get rid of this annoying dialogs when i must use tab twice or hotkey. For example, if you want have a protect to file deletion, you will see another dialog, which ask confirmation for file deletion to the Trash and in this case you need use another hotkey or **once** use tab button. As you see this difference is good for protection, but creates difficulties, because it has different patterns of behavior. Mouse in in this case is not solution - very slow process.